# Visualization 3d objects with Trimesh

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, trimesh

I loaded a 3d object into the program using the function `mesh = trimesh.load('test.obj')`. I want to see what the object looks like now. How can I display the 3d model? What options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

You can plot a Trimesh object as any other 3d object.

First, create a subplot for your 3D object. Check out the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html). Then use a [plot_trisurf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf) method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')


ax.plot_trisurf(trim.vertices[:, 0], trim.vertices[:,1], trim.vertices[:,2], triangles=trim.faces);
```

where trim is a Trimesh object.

You can also use plotly for this purpose, but this example is simple and concise.

Comment: `mesh.show()` is probably the correct way, but I didn't want the extra dependency, and matplotlib was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep it simple, you can use the [`show`](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.html#trimesh.Trimesh.show) method. Note that this requires [pyglet](https://pyglet.org/).

```py
mesh.show()
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python and numpy, you can follow this example [github/trimesh/example](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/main/examples/quick_start.ipynb).